# JRuby in JAR getting different Results from __FILE__

Tags: ruby, jar, jruby

I have packaged ruby files (not compiled) within a Jar.  I am calling them from my Java class using a Scriplet.

Inside my Jar I have all my Ruby Files in the /app Folder.  When I run my code my Java calls RubyClassA.rb.  RubyClassA.rb then calls RubyClassB.rb.  In both classes I run the following code:

```
    puts File.dirname(__FILE__)
```

In RubyClassA I just get: /app.

In RubyClassB I get:  /full/path/to/jar/my_jar.jar!/app

I need this full path (in RubyClassB) to read from other files within the Jar.  However, I would like to read these files from RubyClassA.  I am not sure why I am getting different results from each class.  If anyone could explain what I am doing wrong here, I would highly appreciate it.

EDIT:

- Both these files are located inside the same JAR
- I am using JRuby 1.7.18
- RubyClassA is getting called by a Java Class, RubyClassB is getting called by a Ruby class (RubyClassA)

Comment: seems like the classes are loaded differently ... could you update whether they're actually in the same my_jar.jar and how are you loading them ? also since this feature's details has been changing under the hood, knowing the JRuby version might be useful as well ...

Comment: @Kares -- My Original Post was updated to add this information.